# How to import into Xray Test execution results exported from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jira-xray

Is there any way to import Test Execution result into Xray exported from IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the DICOM file? Basically you just need to save the headers on it with the new information.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what is DICOM file? I have the test result exported from intelliJ and i want to import it into Xray as a test execution result.